# How to insert words into equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to produce equations that have numbers on the right hand side in the style of (eqn 1) rather (1). How would I do this, presumably using a user defined command, but I am having trouble with it.

Example

x + y = 2  (eqn 1)

y = 5 + 4  (eqn 2)

Comment: What about the references? Should they have `eqn` or not?

Comment: @egreg luckily that doesn't come up as I don't seem to reference the equations in the main text. I guess that defeats the purpose of numbering them at all, but this is what the journal wants, so I blindly follow their instructions.

Comment: Doesn't the journal have its own `LaTeX` class?

Comment: @IanThompson Welcome to the world of submitting LaTeX files to biology journals :(. They are literally doing the copy editing on the PDF, despite the fact that their system compiles LaTeX. It's crazy.

Comment: At least they aren't trying to force you to use word.

Comment: @IanThompson They asked me to resubmit the paper in word after it was already accepted. Somehow I won that fight (mostly because the author guidelines explicitly said LaTeX was OK)

Comment: @IanThompson They also forced me to change $p$ to $P$ throughout because the convention for this journal is capital p's for p vaules. When I explained that $p$ was merely a variable the copy editors were confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go a simple way with

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{eqn \arabic{equation}}
```

or with a fancier approach (see [How to move amsmath equation label into LHS margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240333/how-to-move-amsmath-equation-label-into-lhs-margin) for motivation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref processing from \tag processing
\let\tagform@ref\tagform@
\let\maketag@@@ref\maketag@@@
\patchcmd{\eqref}{\tagform@}{\tagform@ref}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tagform@ref}{\maketag@@@}{\maketag@@@ref}{}{}
% redefine \tagform@ to have “eqn” in front of the number
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces eqn #1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We reference equation~\eqref{a} which follows
\begin{align}
x + y &= 2 \label{a}\\
y     &= 5 + 4
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: curious, how would this be treated with \ref? despite it not mattering for me.

Comment: @MHH `\ref` would just print the number, without the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\tag` command from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). In its ordinary form it puts brackets around your label, with the star form it does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x + y &= 2 \tag{eqn 1} \\
y     &= 5 + 4 \tag*{(eqn 2)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: labels]

Alternatively, if you want to put 'eqn' before all equation numbers, you can redefine `\theequation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{eqn \@arabic\c@equation}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x + y &= 2 \\
y     &= 5 + 4
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, although I needed align*, without the "*" a (1) would be stuck at the bottom of the set of the equations

Comment: Only if you put a spurious `\\\` at the end of the last equation.

Comment: actually not for me, I get the (1) at the bottom without it strangely enough

Comment: @MHH --- weird. If you can make a small example that reproduces this behaviour, I suggest posting a question about it.